# Name in edit state upon creation of collection

Tags: collections, outliner

Is there a function in Blender Outliner to automatically have the name of a collection in an editable state when i create it? I always have to F2 a "Collection 187" and its just an extra step. Nobody wants or should have the kind of workflow where they leave those default names anyway. i looked around prefs and dont see this as an setting. Just checking to see if this is a function, option, hotkey command or just a QOL nice to have wish

Comment: Nope. If you think it might be a nice addition you could suggest it on [Right-Click Select](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/?sorting=hot). Of course you could always double-click the name in the Outliner to edit it...

Comment: Double-Click, F2, whatever. Actually what got me thinking about it is this heavy scene im in. Everything is taking so long i cant tell if my double-clicks and F2's are registering  There are other softwares that do that open edit thing for some of the things they do. Its just a nice proactive timesaver. Thanks for responding. I'll suggest on right click if it hasnt already been

Answer (score 4):

In the 3D View, or Outliner, if you select any objects to be included / moved to a collection, and hit <kbd>M</kbd>, you will be presented with a choice of collections to move to, with the top item being 'New Collection'.

If you select 'New Collection', you will be dropped straight into an edit-box to name it.

I agree, it's odd that if you right-click in the Outliner and hit 'New', that doesn't put the new collection's name straight into Edit Mode.  Sounds like a good [Right-Click-Select](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/?sorting=hot) suggestion, to me.

Comment: it could have been easy with an operator and adding as quick fave https://snipboard.io/8wlzhf.jpg but unfortunately `bpy.ops.outliner.item_rename(use_active=True)` cannot be used in scripts.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Good shot! ..and .. very annoying :)

Comment: i found out that `item_rename` will work if overriden with the deprecated override method. but i will need a solution for https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/302094/how-can-i-fully-select-a-collection-using-python-with-blue-highlight in order to solve the querent's issue.