# How can I fully select a collection using python with blue highlight?

Tags: python, scripting, collections, outliner, select

I have found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72249348/blender-python-api-how-to-select-a-collection-in-the-outliner) and several other threads but nothing with any legit answers. We can somewhat select a collection using for example this script that "selects" the one at index 2:

```
collections = bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection.children
bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection = collections[2]
```

But that doesn't fully select the collection as can be seen below. It is not blue in highlight. This can be proven when you press <kbd>F2</kbd> in the Outliner, it will attempt to rename the one in blue highlight instead of the supposedly newly "selected" collection.

[image]

When I click a collection I see the command `bpy.ops.outliner.item_activate(deselect_all=True)` but adding this to the script doesn't help. How do you fully select a collection with python or is this even possible? The solution for this question will help solve [this thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/301859/name-in-edit-state-upon-creation-of-collection).

Comment: Does the accepted answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/127403/change-active-collection?noredirect=1&lq=1  help?

Comment: @curious_1 no it does the same thing, no blue highlight, just the white highlight. the code in the accepted answer is even worse with the unnecessary iteration i think.

Comment: As you witnessed the iteration is because of nested collections, in a trivial case with rank 1 children it isn't useful since they can be accessed easily. I think you've hit the same design [roadblock](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/unique-identifier-for-layer-collections/23966) as I did some time ago, the outliner / view layer python API is lacking several utility functions to access and manage layer collections.

Answer (score 6):

Each outliner area has individual selection (blue highlight).

But only one active collection as seen below (gray highlight on icon).

[image]

If you press `F2` in any one area, it renames the active selection in the area where your mouse is on.
But if you create an object, it will always be created under the active collection.

The `bpy.ops.outliner.item_activate(extend=False, extend_range=False, deselect_all=False)` operator internally uses mouse position to select and activate items.

Also there is no `active_item` like attribute associated with the `OUTLINER` space you can use.
[image]

So you can't use python to manipulate active selection in the `OUTLINER`.

However you can use `bpy.data.collections` to modify `collection` properties.

Please do tell what you cannot achieve without that selection.

If you want to rename a collection using python use any one of these:

```
bpy.data.collections[0].name = "new_name"
bpy.data.collections['current_name'].name = "new_name"
```

Comment: Do you use some addon to display all available attributes of an area? BTW, maybe `bpy.ops.outliner.item_activate()` could be run with proper context override...

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady [API_Browser](https://github.com/JayReigns/API_Browser)

Comment: i initially downvoted the answer because it did not answer the question but now with the added details, i can make more sense of the situation and now upvoted it, thank you very much!

Comment: ok so basically the answer to my question is that it is impossible to change the active selection via python.

Answer (score -1):

> ok so basically the answer to my question is that it is impossible to
> change the active selection via python.

-> Technically this is possible.

-> Your question was "How can I fully select a collection using python with blue highlight?"

-> Your question does not mention a specific api to be required as part of the solution to the problem you stated in your question.

So an Answer is:

````
import pyautogui
import time
import pydirectinput
 
##assumes that u work in 1080p and with the standard window-arrangement in blender 3.6
x, y = 1655, 105
pyautogui.moveTo(x, y)
pyautogui.click(button='left')
# Wait for a moment
time.sleep(0.5)
# Simulate a scroll down
pyautogui.scroll(-5000)
time.sleep(0.5)
pyautogui.moveTo(x, 340)
time.sleep(0.5)
pydirectinput.keyDown('shift')
pyautogui.click(button='left')
pydirectinput.keyUp('shift')
```
````

Comment: It's a very "ugly" solution. Plus it will fail in most cases, because of the coordinates so it doesn't actually work. Technically, it exists, yes, but if you judged this as an advice to a friend who is looking for help with this... Well, it's a terrible advice. Deserves a downvote the way I see it...

Comment: beauty is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: If you hover over the downvote button it has a tooltip that says: "This answer is not useful". I think it fits. It's my honest vote. Maybe others will find it useful and upvote.

Comment: "It's a very "ugly" solution" -> u admitted it is a solution according to ur own standards, but judged it by your own pov on beauty. How about putting some brains into getting up a solution yourself instead of trying to invalidate / talk down on mine ?

 I believe you're not acting accordingly to the rules of blender.stackexchange & your comment is proof of bigotry, which is why i flagged it. Hope you didn't remove the flag yourself. tbh, don't care about your pov, but am in the talks with higher ups concerning your unprofessional conduct as a mod.

Let's see how the Questioneer decides.

Comment: It being not elegant is not the only reason I think it's not useful. It will not work in most cases because it's based on pixel coordinates and UI state. It is not useful for average user and it is not useful as a Python solution because it could not be used in an add-on. "How about putting some brains into getting up a solution yourself" - a good solution does not seem to exist in this case. Blender's Python API does not seem to have functionality for this.

Comment: If I was to give an "ugly" solution, I think I would try to explore `bpy.ops.outliner.select_walk()` operator. It seems to make the highlighted collection active so it should be possible to do it until the needed one is selected, but that is also not a good solution...